# Grunt livereload (grunt watch) not working with Apache with Symfony2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I've set up an AngularJS setup to start working with Symfony2 as the backend with AngularJS as the frontend. So what I've set up is the following (having used [generator-symfony](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-symfony) as the base:

- `/app` contains the standard Symfony2 application
- `/grunt` contains the standard AngularJS scripts (same as `/app` when using only AngularJS)
- `/src` contains the Symfony2 source code
- `/vendor` composer dependencies
- `/web` symfony main route (contains `app.php` and `app_dev.php`)
- `/web/dist` the distribution build for grunt (`grunt build`)

I've pointed `http://localhost/` to the `/grunt` directory and `http://localhost/api` to the `/web` directory, which works great, I can access both the angular application and the Symfony2 application

I've added a index.html file in my `/grunt` directory with some HTML, and all works fine, as I can access this and refresh it etc.

Now my problem is that the livereload feature doesn't work. I've just adjusted the `Gruntfile.js` from the [generator-symfony](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-symfony) I used (found below). Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong with my configuration?

(I'd love to show only the relevant bits but I've no idea where the problem resides).

```
/**
 * Gruntfile
 * @see http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
 *
 * Plugin and task configuration for Grunt.
 *
 * Based on the yeoman webapp generator
 * @see https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp
 */

// Enable strict mode
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({

        /**
         * Paths
         */
        yeoman: {
            app: 'grunt',
            dist: 'web/dist'
        },

        /****************************************************************
         * Grunt Plugin Configuration
         ****************************************************************/

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-watch
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
         *
         * Run predefined tasks whenever watched file patterns are added, changed or deleted.
         */
        watch: {
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:watch', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: {
                        options: {
                            base: [
                                '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                                '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{<%= yeoman.dist %>,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-connect
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect
         *
         * Start a connect web server.
         *
         * Note: this server only runs as long as grunt is running. Once grunt's tasks
         * have completed, the web server stops. This behavior can be changed with the
         * keepalive option, and can be enabled ad-hoc by running the task like
         * grunt connect:keepalive
         */
        connect: {
            test: {
                options: {
                    hostname: 'localhost', // change to '0.0.0.0' for external access
                    port: 9000,
                    base: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        'test',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-clean
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean
         *
         * Clean files and folders.
         */
        clean: {
            test: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-jshint
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint
         *
         * Validate files with JSHint.
         */
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        /**
         * grunt-mocha
         * @see https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha
         *
         * Automatically run client-side mocha specs via grunt/mocha/PhantomJS.
         */
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-compass
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass
         *
         * Compile Sass to CSS using Compass.
         */
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scss',
                cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css',
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false
            },
            watch: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true,
                    force: false
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: false,
                    force: true,
                    environment: 'production'
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-autoprefixer
         * @see https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer
         *
         * Parses CSS and adds vendor-prefixed CSS properties using the "Can I Use"
         * database (http://caniuse.com/).
         */
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/',
                        src: '{,*/}*.css',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-rev
         * @see https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev
         *
         * Static file asset revisioning through content hashing
         */
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-usemin
         * @see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin
         *
         * Replaces references to non-optimized scripts or stylesheets
         * into a set of HTML files (or any templates/views).
         */
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            options: {
                root: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/../' // This allows us to use /dist/ in the manifests
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/../']
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-htmlmin
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
         *
         * Minify HTML.
         */
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                     // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                     //collapseWhitespace: true,
                     collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                     removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                     removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                     useShortDoctype: true,
                     removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                     removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        src: '{,*/}*.html',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-imagemin
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin
         *
         * Minify PNG and JPEG images.
         */
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-svgmin
         * @see https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-svgmin
         *
         * Minify SVG using SVGO.
         */
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-contrib-copy
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy
         *
         * Copy files and folders.
         */
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                            'fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        /**
         * grunt-modernizr
         * @see https://github.com/doctyper/grunt-modernizr
         *
         * A Modernizr builder for your project. Sifts through your project files,
         * gathers up your references to Modernizr tests and outputs a lean,
         * mean Modernizr machine.
         */
        modernizr: {
            devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
            ],
            uglify: true
        },

        /**
         * grunt-concurrent
         * @see https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent
         *
         * Running slow tasks like Coffee and Sass concurrently can potentially
         * improve your build time significantly. This task is also useful if
         * you need to run multiple blocking tasks like nodemon and watch at once.
         */
        concurrent: {
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass:dist',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },

        // DISABLED - Configured via grunt-usemin
        /**
         * grunt-contrib-cssmin
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin
         *
         * Compress CSS files.
         */
        // cssmin: {
        // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
        // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
        // `index.html` will take care of minification, e.g.
        //
        //     <!-- build:css({<%= yeoman.dist %>,app}) styles/main.css -->
        //
        // dist: {
        //     files: {
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/main.css': [
        //             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
        //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css'
        //         ]
        //     }
        // }
        // },

        // DISABLED - Configured via grunt-usemin
        /**
         * grunt-contrib-concat
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat
         *
         * Concatenate files.
         */
        /*concat: {
         dist: {}
         },*/

        // DISABLE - Support for RequireJS has been deprecated in usemin 2.0.0
        // @see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/112
        /**
         * grunt-contrib-requirejs
         * @see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs
         *
         * Optimize RequireJS projects.
         * Note: There is no difference between declaring your require config
         * in your Gruntfile and using a separate requirejs config file.
         */
        /*requirejs: {
         dist: {
         // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
         options: {
         baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
         name: 'main',
         mainConfigFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js',
         out: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/main.js',
         optimize: 'none',
         preserveLicenseComments: false,
         useStrict: true,
         wrap: true
         }
         }
         },*/
        /**
         * grunt-bower-requirejs
         * @see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs
         *
         * Automagically wire-up installed Bower components into
         * your RequireJS config.
         */
        /*bower: {
         options: {
         exclude: ['modernizr', 'detectizr']
         },
         all: {
         rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
         }
         }*/

    });

    /****************************************************************
     * Grunt Task Definitions
     ****************************************************************/

    /**
     * Test task
     */
    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:test',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        // @todo
        //'mocha'
    ]);

    /**
     * Build task
     */
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        // Disable if usemin has no css and no js
        'concat',
        // Disable if usemin has no css
        'cssmin',
        // Disable if usemin has no js
        'uglify',
        'modernizr',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    /**
     * Default task
     */
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);

};
```

If any more information is needed, please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, it turned out that I had to inject the live-reload JS file, however, I was always under the impression that this was automatically appended at the end using the DOM, but I guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you find a solution. I was having the same struggle you went through and end up with a very simple solution, and I wrote [here](http://allenhwkim.tumblr.com/post/71559444236/the-simplest-livereload-with-grunt)

I made a very simple script that I understand, since I just needed to refresh page automatically.

```
(function() {
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:35729"); 
  ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
    if ((JSON.parse(msg.data)).command == "reload") {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }; 
})();
```